# PeterBlum PeterBlum.DES.Date._CurrentCenturyStart

Tags: c#, asp.net, peterblum

using v 4.0.7.500 , C# ASP
How I can use the PeterBlum.DES.Date.CurrentCenturyStart property to obtain the start date of the current century?

My problem is  - when i checked year>2029 on datePicker this year override by Peter's validation script and become to: 1900 + twolast digit of year, when i checked year<2029 it 2000 + twolast digit of year(it was fine)

I try:
change the format from dd/mm/yy to dd/mm/yyyy
and add Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax=2099;

So i think maybe PeterBlum.DES.Date.CurrentCenturyStart property can resolve this issue.